# Show/Hide subsections in the table of contents of a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am new in LaTeX and I need some help in doing a `beamer` presentation. I have a dense table of contents with 6 `sections` and 15 `subsections` in total. I would like to have a table of contents which lights up each section one by one and shows only the subsections of the selected section and hide all the other subsections. Like this:

When I light up Section 1

> Section 1
>
> - subsection 1
> - subsection 2
> - subsection 3
>
> Section 2
>
> Section 4
>
> Section 5
>
> Section 6

When I light up Section 2

> Section 1
>
> Section 2
>
> - subsection 1
> - subsection 2
> - subsection 3
>
> Section 4
>
> Section 5
>
> Section 6

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103458/31058?

Comment: Maybe you want to adapt the solution from the link I provided by replacing `AtBeginSubsection` by `AtBeginSection` and the `show/shaded/hide` value for the subsection by `show/show/hide`?

Comment: Thank you Ludovic! This is quite close to what I was looking for.

The only difference is that I want this show/hide of subsection only at the begin of the presentation, where I have the table of content, not at the beginning of each section.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103458/31058), I came to that code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\mytableofcontents}[0]{
\multido{\I=1+1}{\totvalue{section}}{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \setcounter{section}{\I}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[
    currentsection,
    sectionstyle=show/show,
    subsectionstyle=show/show/hide,
  ]
  \end{frame}
}
\setcounter{section}{0}
}

\begin{document}

\mytableofcontents

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame} test  \total{section} \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here are the first three frames:

[image: First slide]

[image: Second slide]

[image: Third slide]

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I wanted to provide an answer to a similar question, because searching for that answer was how I stumbled upon this page. On page 99 of the [BeamerUserGuide](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), it indicates the options available for the `\tableofcontents` command. Using the option `\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]` only reveals the subsections for the current section.